# page break in DataList

Tags: asp.net

How can i implement a page break in a Data List after showing four items.
Below is my code where i have binded the DataList with a DataTable.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server"  BackColor="White" 
            BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
            GridLines="Horizontal" Width="90%">
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />

            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />

            <ItemStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table width="100%" height="240px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTestID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Font-Size="32"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                          <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src= '<%# Eval("PhotoPath") %>' Height="180" Width="150"  />
                        </td>  
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        </asp:DataList>
```

My actual problem is i have to do bulk printing. Currently when i do, i get half data in one page and half in other page. 
I thought if page-break is the solution to my problem

Comment: This link might be of some user for you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1259469.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

Through CSS, you can set `page-break-after: always`

Comment: How can i after repeating 4 items on page. i have already applied a page break but still get those half data